# Erro - Visualizar uma imagem salva na base de dados tipo BLOB

Tags: php, html, sql, upload, phpmyadmin

Possuo um script php que já faz a inserção de imagens na base de dados, conforme é mostrado abaixo:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conexao.inc.php";
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.iso-8859-1', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese' ); 
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Fortaleza' );
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$expiro = $_POST['expiro'];
$legenda = $_POST['legenda'];
$imagem = $_FILES['imag']['tmp_name'];
$tamanho = $_FILES['imag']['size'];
$tipo = $_FILES['imag']['type'];
$nome = $_FILES['imag']['name'];
if($imagem != "none"){
    $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb");
    $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
    $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
    fclose($fp);
    $sql = $conn -> query("insert into slide values('$titulo','$legenda','$conteudo','$expiro','".date('y-m-d')."')");
    if($sql){
        header("location: index.php");
    }
}?>
```

O código de inserção funciona e o mesmo pode ser visualizado na base de dados desta maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de visualização está abaixo:

```
<?php session_start();
include "conexao.inc.php";
$sql = $conn -> query("select * from slide order by data_cri");    
while($linha = $sql -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       if($cont==0){
         echo "<div class='item active'><center><figure><figcaption align='center'><label>".$linha['Título']."</label></figcaption><img src='".$linha['imagem']."' alt='Erro, manutenção necessária!' /></figure></center></div>";
       }else{
          echo "<div class='item'><center><figure><figcaption align='center'><label>".$linha['Título']."</label></figcaption><img src=".$linha['imagem']." alt='Erro, manutenção necessária!' /></figure></center></div>";
       }
}?>
```

O código do arquivo conexao.inc.php é este:

```
<?php
try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=intranet', 'root', 'aniger_2017');
$conn -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "<script> alert('Erro na conexão!'); </script>";
}   ?>
```

A forma de como é mostrado a imagem no sistema é da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dar encode em base64 antes de mostra-lo:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($linha['imagem'])." alt='Erro, manutenção necessária!' />
```

Comment: Ele agora não mostra  a imagem, ele mostra o alt='Erro, manutenção necessária!'